# How implement loader view like DotsLoader, Spinkit etc. on Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio

In my project I want try to add a loader view, specially DotsLoader. I added its dependency

```
implementation ("com.agrawalsuneet.androidlibs:dotsloader:1.4")
```

but it's not working, I don't know why. I searched on Google and found a lot more dependencies, but those were also not working.

After that. I tried Spinkit loader with the dependency:
implementation ("com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.4.0")

but it also does not work.

I don't know what happened. I use `androidx` with SDK `34`.

If anyone knows a solution for my problem, please reply.

Comment: It's hard to help you when you don't give us more details. What do you mean by "it's not working"? Is there any error message? Please show us the relevant part of your code and tell us more about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First you to check your gradle is not handling any library. You need to check maven and google added in gradle?

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
      
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

If you need animated loaders then you need lottie animations search this library and add in your project then lot of animation on this website you can use in android project